# JSP and JSTL with the Onclick method

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, jstl

I have 2 links. In a session i store some data. I want if a user click in a specific link to look into the session and if the appropriate value contained, to continue. Else an AJAX pop up block will appears.

JAVASCRRIPT pop up block

```
 function displaymessage(title,message,close)
 {

        resultReturn= $.confirm({
        'title'     : title, 
        'message'   : message
        'buttons'   : {
        close/*'Yes'*/  : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                                    'caption': close,
                'action': function(){}
                        }           
                        }
                          });
   }
```

JSP with JSTL tags:

```
    <div class="header">
        <a href="<c:url value='/home'/>">
        <a href="<c:url value='/further'/>">
    </div>

     <c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(data, 'mykey')}"> 
            <a id="get" class="right keepScrollPosition" 
               onclick="return displaymessage('<spring:message code="access.denied.title"/>'
                   ,'<spring:message code="access.denied.message"/>','<spring:message code="access.denied.close"/>');" 
               href="#"  /></a> 
        </c:if>
```

For example, if in the session contained the value 'mykey',then can go into the link home, else a pop up will appears. In case, in the session contained the value 'mypassword' and select the further link can continue, but if select the home link a pop up block will appears.
*I'm stuck and i need some help on how can i do this.Please help me*

UPDATE

I'm trying the following script but it doesn't work:

```
  <li><a href="<c:url value='/home/'/>"<spring:message code="home_page"/>
        onclick="if(<c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(data, 'mykey')}">){
                    return displaymessage('<spring:message code="access.denied.title"/>' 
               ,'<spring:message code="access.denied.message"/>','<spring:message code="access.denied.close"/>')" href="#" ;
       }
       </a>
   </li>
```

Comment: I don't know how can i do this.I need some directions

Comment: Don't know how to do what specifically?

Comment: How to write the appropriate script in order to check in the session if the appropriate value contained.Probably i need an if statement combined with the onclick method. I update my code,please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use client-side JS to check a server-side value held in the session.  Instead, you need to use JS to make a GET call to a request mapping which runs servers-side code to check the session.  Flow could be as follows:

1. User clicks button/image/something on page
2. JS fires from click, makes AJAX call (e.g. `$.get`) to request mapping `/check_session.do`
3. Request mapping checks session for value, returns true or false as JSON
4. Client-side JS processes returned JSON, blocks or proceeds based on returned value

Alternatively, use JSTL to access the session and write the session field's value to a hidden form field on the page, which the client-side JS then reads.  Example: http://www.steve-farmer.com/examples/el/ui/ses-attr-name.jsp

Comment: Thank you for your response. <a onclick="if(<c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(data, 'mykey')}"/>){return displaymessage('title','message','close'); href="#" }">. Here i'm using this tag in order to check at the session. If this is TRUE(i.e contained the value) then it has to call the displaymessage method. This specific tag i'm using here i used it and in another part of the site and is working perfectly fine. But i don't know why this doesn't call the method displaymessage.Probably a syntax error?Could you help me?